# Importing multiple datasets in the same Excel sheet using Table

Tags: list-manipulation, import

I have 15 datasets in a .xlsx/.format that total to 30 columns of data, and would like to import them all at once. The data are ordered every two columns (columns 1 and 2 are dataset1, columns 3 and 4 are dataset2, etc...)

My first thought was to use Table to import the data into an indexed variable, like so:

```
data = Table[Import["filepath.xlsx"][[1, All, {i, i + 1}]], {i, 1, 30, 2}]
```

While the data are successfully imported, I come across an issue where all of columns that are shorter then the longest column are filled up to the length of the longest column. For example, the first column, which is shorter, has extra values that look like `{x(1),y(1)},{x(end),y(end)},{,},{,},{,},...`

I can still plot the data just fine, but I encounter errors down the line and would like to find a more elegant way to work around this issue that doesn't involve importing 15 different excel sheets.

Comment: just work with `Select` or `Cases` to strip the blank rows after import.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import and store all data that contains `numdatasets` different data sets:

```
data = First@Import["yourfile.xlsx"]
```

Partition into datasets; use `DeleteCases` to remove empty rows:

```
datasets = Table[DeleteCases[{"", ""}]@data[[All, i ;; i + 1]], {i, 1, 2 numdatasets, 2}]
```

Comment: I'm not at my computer right now, but I don't quite understand the bounds you're using for `Table.` Regardless, I understand what you're doing here, so thanks for the help!

Comment: @acquisto2 I meant it this way: suppose that you have 15 datasets in your data (so `numdatasets = 15`); then your iterator in `Table` must go up to 30, i.e. twice the number of datasets. That's where the `2 numdatasets` upper limit for $i$ came from.

Comment: Yep! Works great, thank you!